# How to clear cache for my UIWebView's loadHtmlString?

Tags: caching, uiwebview

I have some embedded html in my application bundle.I'm using loadHtmlString to load it. At the same time there are some image files in my documents folder.I want to replace my img in html with the one in my documents folder. For example, here is the sample html I have:

```
       <div id="image">
            <a href="image">
                <img src="@image" class="center">               
            </a>
        </div>
```

I'm using the following code to replace the @image to the file path in my documents:

```
    NSString* imgFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:///%@/%@",
                         [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Images"],@"myimage.png"];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@image" withString:imgFile];   

    NSURL* baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:text baseURL:baseUrl];
```

(text is the html text of my html file).

It works the first time when this code is called. But for example, if I modify myimage.png and call the code again, the image before I modified is still showed. (I have check my file in my document folder, it's already modified correctly).

I suspect it's caused by the cache. Can anybody advise?

Thanks

**Note:**

It is caused by the cache. I solved the problem by using the following method to force UIWebView to load a fresh copy of image:

```
NSString* imgFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:///%@/%@?t=%d",
                         [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Images"],@"myimage.png",time(NULL)];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@image" withString:imgFile];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by add a time in my url. So the image will not be cached. Please refer to my questions. The question is consider to be closed.

Comment: I have the same problem! But in my case I can't change image name. I'v got to clean my web view... any ideas?

Comment: My solution is to change the url of the image so that it forces to get the image without using cache. 

Why you can't change the image url? You have to load the image anyway, right?

Comment: I have changed image url! Works fine now. It was a difficult thing to change url. The project is extremly big and it's not my project. Anyway your solution turned out to be the only woking one. Thx!

Comment: I've tried a few other options, for example, to change cache policy etc, but none of them work. My method is the simplest in my case. Sorry I have no idea how to simplify it in your application.